# Bad Authentication Data with Twitter Account Activity API

Tags: curl, twitter

I am following this guide to attempt to create a webhook using the new Premium Twitter Account Activity API that we have since got access too

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/quick-start/enterprise-account-activity-api

I am using ngrok note the URL below has been changed for security - here is my cURL request (again the credentials have been changed for security)

```
curl --request POST --url 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/webhooks.json?url=https%3A%2F%2F1cd9exxx.ngrok.io%2Fwebhook%2Ftwitter%3Fcrc_token%3D1234' --header 'authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="6stxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_nonce="GENERATED", oauth_signature="GENERATED", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="GENERATED", oauth_token="135453118-xxxx", oauth_version="1.0"'
```

I am always getting the following response :

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've to generate the as 'GENERATED' marked fields.

Probably you can use `twurl`. It makes the OAuth 1.0 handling much simpler.

Take a look at `twurl`: https://github.com/twitter/twurl

If you use `twurl`:

1. Login via `twurl authorize` and follow the instructions.
2. Register your webhook endpoint `twurl -X POST "/1.1/account_activity/all/<<your created env>>/webhooks.json?url=<<your url>>"`

If you've implemented your webhook endpoint correctly, you get a 200 status code.